# Issue on output's return value

Tags: php, output

Currently I am using a file with css and all.I have a problem as i am using php output between many html tags. The menu consist of the hard coded pages which is included with the php `require_once`. However, i also want to add in some pages from my database.

The Problem: The menu only shows 1 page name from my database when i have 2. It is displaying the 2nd page's name i have made. However clicking on it, it calls up the content from the 1st page.

The page name from my database is added using php output after the `<ul id="menu-toc">`

The page's content from my database is added at the bottom of the "The Page" section.

update: I've changed the placing of the while loop before the  to after the

Pattern of css

```
<div class="bb-item" id="abscess">
<div class="content">
<div class="scroller">

Content

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The Page

```
function find_condition() {

    global $connection;

    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM pages ";
    $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
    $query .= "AND subject_id = 2 ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
    $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($page_set);
    return $page_set;
}


$two = find_condition();
while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($two)) { 

$pagearray = $page['menu_name'];  
?>  




    <ul id="menu-toc" class="menu-toc">
    <li class="menu-toc-current">               
    <a href="abscess">ABSCESS</a></li>
    <li><a href="apthous ulcer">APTHOUS ULCER</a></li>
    <li><a href="bad breath">BAD BREATH</a></li>

    <?php

    $output = "<li>";
    $output .= "<a href=\"";
    $output .= $pagearray;
    $output .= "\">";
    $output .= $pagearray;
    $output .= "</a></li>";
}
echo $output;


?>


</ul>

</div>


<div class="bb-custom-wrapper">
    <div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock">
    <?php require_once("abscess.php"); ?>
    <?php require_once("apthousulcer.php"); ?>
    <?php require_once("bad breath.php"); ?>

    <?php
    $two= find_condition();
while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($two)) {

    $pagearray = $page['menu_name'];
    $content = $page['content'];

    $output .= "<div class=\"bb-item\" id=\"";
    $output .= $pagearray;
    $output .= "\">";
    $output .= "<div class=\"content\">";
    $output .= "<div class=\"scroller\">";
    $output .= "<h2>";
    $output .= $pagearray;
    $output .= "</h2>";
    $output .= $content;
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "</div>";
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting a new `<ul>` each time through the `while` loop. You should just do that once, before the loop. You're also reinitializing `$output` each time through the loop, but not printing it in the loop. So you're just printing the last assignment of `output` after the loop is done.

```
$two = find_condition();
?>
    <ul id="menu-toc" class="menu-toc">
    <li class="menu-toc-current">               
    <a href="abscess">ABSCESS</a></li>
    <li><a href="apthous ulcer">APTHOUS ULCER</a></li>
    <li><a href="bad breath">BAD BREATH</a></li>

    <?php
while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($two)) {   

    $pagearray = $page['menu_name'];


    ?>


    <?php

    $output = "<li>";
    $output .= "<a href=\"";
    $output .= $pagearray;
    $output .= "\">";
    $output .= $pagearray;
    $output .= "</a></li>";
    echo $output;
}


?>
```

Comment: Erm, i followed your advice. I still have that issue. I will now edit my codes to show how it looks like now

Comment: Don't remove the original code from the question. How are readers in the supposed to know what the original question was? My answer only makes sense in terms of that. If you want to show what you've edited your code to, add it as an UPDATE at the end, instead of replacing the original code.

Comment: You still have `echo $output` outside the loop, so you're just echoing the last row.

Comment: Alright, sorry i didn't thought of the consequence of removing the original code. I placed it back to how it was with an update on the question itself. I'm now trying your solution.

Comment: I added both the outputs of the content as well as the page name into the loop, however the content (bottom of The Page) output shows only the first page's content and a blank page. Thanks again for your solutions.

Comment: Sorry, i figured out the issue, it's because there of the output being output.= at the bottom side. I've switched it to = and it works now. Thank you very much for your help and again, im sorry for editting the question earlier.